# How to avoid setting aws config as env variable externally while using dynamoose.js

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, amazon-dynamodb, dynamoose

My aws config doesn't work unless I set it externally through env variable

db connection works only if I set the credentials externally like,

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=abcde
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=abcde
export AWS_REGION=ap-south-1
export AWS_DYNAMODB_ENDPOINT="http://localhost:8000"
```

It doesn't work if I don't set these externally. For example if I set it in code like the following, it does not work.

```
dynamoose.AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId:'abcde',
  secretAccessKey:'abcde',
  region:'ap-south-1',
  endpoint:'http://localhost:8000'
});
```

I don't want to set config in any variable externally. Is there a way to just manage this in nodejs code?

These are the alternates I have tried/considered

1. Setting env variable in the code, this doesn't work either

   process.env.AWS_REGION='ap-south-1';
2. I read about dotenv package. But it is recommended that it should be used for dev only and not production (I am not sure if that will work)

Please help me resolve this. How do I manage the config in code only?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that you are creating or requiring your Dynamoose models before you run the `dynamoose.AWS.config.update` method.

Make sure that `dynamoose.AWS.config.update` is the very first method you call, and you haven't created or initialized any Dynamoose related things before.

For example.

```
const dynamoose = require('dynamoose');
dynamoose.AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId:'abcde',
  secretAccessKey:'abcde',
  region:'ap-south-1',
  endpoint:'http://localhost:8000'
});
const Model = require('./models/MyModel'); // should happen after `dynamoose.AWS.config.update`
```

Another trick I would try to do is enable debug logging and go through the logs to see what is happening. You can enable Dynamoose logging by running `export DEBUG=dynamoose*`, then rerunning the script.

Comment: Thank you @Charlie Fish. The sequence was right.  It got resolved by loading the config from a json file using loadFromPath.  **AWS.config.loadFromPath('./aws.json');** This worked for me. I would like know the reason behind this though.

Comment: @AmitaMohite Glad it worked for you! The reason is that Dynamoose by default checks to see if the table is active, and if it hasn't been created it will create the table and update it. So it needs correct config information in order to preform those tasks. You can edit these options about trying to create the table and such in the documentation [here](https://dynamoosejs.com/api#dynamoosemodelname-schema-options). Feel free to upvote and accept the answer if it helped you. Good luck!

Comment: I have used the same config which I was using earlier. The only difference is first I used **dynamoose.AWS.config.update(awsConfig);(this didn't work)** where aws config was in a js file, accessed using a require statement**, var awsConfig = require('./config/aws');**.    Whereas what I mentioned in the above comment worked.

Comment: @AmitaMohite If I understand correctly you are asking why `dynamoose.AWS.config.loadFromPath` works while `dynamoose.AWS.config.update` does not. There are so many reasons for why that is the case, and without more context and information it'd hard to debug. I would start by console.logging the `awsConfig` you created. If I had to guess, that is undefined. Did you remember to use `module.exports` to export your file? loadFromPath takes in a JSON file, but if you are trying to require it, you have to make sure to make it a JavaScript file instead of a JSON file, and use `module.exports`.

Comment: I checked all these things like if it is undefined, i did use module.exports. I had console logged the config just before config.update statement, it was fine. I have also tried giving the config directly into the config.update statement in app.js as mentioned above in my question. That didn't work too.  May be I need to take some time and debug to know why is it so. Just curious to know. Will debug this off my work time and understand.   Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with newer version syntax is changed and could be find here .

https://dynamoosejs.com/guide/Dynamoose/#dynamooseawssdk

```
const sdk = dynamoose.aws.sdk; // require("aws-sdk");
sdk.config.update({
    "accessKeyId": "AKID",
    "secretAccessKey": "SECRET",
    "region": "us-east-1"
});
```